# Returning a query to a Laravel resource keeps giving 500

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build an array of details to pass to a dashboard resource, but im running into some issues when trying to pass the data to the resource.

In my controller im building up queries like so;

```php
$user = auth()->user();

$teams = Team::query()
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->get();

$jobs = Job::query()
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->get();

return new DashboardResource($user, $jobs, $teams);
```

Then in the resource;

```php
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'name' => $user->name,
        'teams' => TeamResource::collection($this->teams),
        'jobs' => JobResource::collection($this->jobs),
    ];
}
```

I keep getting an issue like;

```
Property [jobs] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

I think i may be doing this quite wrong

Comment: check setter function that refer to $this->jobs

Answer (score 0):

JsonResource constructor only expect one argument.
You should create your relations for Teams and Jobs inside your User model and then in your resource call `$user->teams` and `$user->jobs`